# Search in files using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How can we search in file using eclipse ide ?

The search is under CTRL+H but I would like extend the search to files that may not be in the current workspace / project, just like what we can do with  Visual Studio.

Comment: As far as I know, the file search scope is limited to the workspace. You cannot search outside.

Comment: this is the answser I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I know, the file search scope is limited to the workspace.
>   You cannot search outside.

*Best answer I got for this problem, thanks to @Marcell Fülöp*